# How to move multiple images back to the center in CSS?

Tags: css, image

I am having trouble moving my x4 images back into the middle of the page.

My CSS code has remained the same however my images have moved left and I need to move them back to the center. I have tried display:block and using floats but this has not worked.

This is the current code which was centered previously. Please let me know if you have any suggestions!

```
img {
  margin: 40px 8px 0 8px;
}
```

Comment: Either use `width: 100%; height: auto` or `object-fit: cover` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: Thank you for replying - i did try both these options but it did not work unfortunately. It just stretched the images the size of the page. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple kinds of *centering*, do you mean:

### Centering images on the same line?

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<img src="//placecage.com/100/100">
<img src="//placecage.com/100/100">
<img src="//placecage.com/100/100">
<img src="//placecage.com/100/100">
```

### Centering images on the same column?

```css
img {
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="//placecage.com/100/100">
<img src="//placecage.com/100/100">
<img src="//placecage.com/100/100">
<img src="//placecage.com/100/100">
```

### Centering images vertically and horizontally ?

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<img src="//placecage.com/100/100">
<img src="//placecage.com/100/100">
<img src="//placecage.com/100/100">
<img src="//placecage.com/100/100">
```

Answer (score 0):

### This should help

```css
img {
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately that did not work. It stretched the images to fit the page so it didn't centre.

Comment: use background-size: cover

Comment: Hi Naveen - thank you but that also did not work. I have 4 images that are placed on the left and they will not center. I tried different padding and margins but they either just make them really big or still do not center.